# Getting error during magento 2 Installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I am getting the error in Magento 2 installation.

** Error:**

[image]

Comment: You're missing libsodium php extension it seems, it is required for 2.3.2 version @vikaskumar

Comment: what is your php and magento version?

Comment: Php version 7.2.19 and Magento Version 2.3.2

Comment: libsodium extension is not mentioned on magento website @Prathap Gunasekaran

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Required-libsodium-upgrade-for-latest-Magento-release/ba-p/134808

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23405

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu
Install php-libsodium by entering the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-libsodium
```

Restart the server and you can install then

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Install Phplibsodium by entering below commands:

wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz

tar -xzvf libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libsodium-1.0.18

./configure

make && make check

sudo make install

sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install -f libsodium

sudo echo "extension=sodium" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

php -m | grep sodium